# Определить является ли число k степенью 3

Tags: c++, c

помогите решить данную задачу ?
Определить является ли число k степенью 3.

Comment: По моему тут только делить)

Comment: вы даже не пытаетесь, да?

Comment: @vp_arth Делить до того момента пока не получится 1 и остаток от деления будет равен 0?

Comment: @goldstar_labs , Пытаюсь но пока нету представления как это можно сделать (

Comment: Делить, пока больше 1 и вернуть false в любой момент, где остаток от деления на 3 не 0

Comment: @vp_arth умножать, вроде, быстрее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool is_deg3(const int num) {
    int value = 1;

    while ((value < num) && (value < INT_MAX / 3)) {
        value *= 3;
    }

    return value == num;
}
```

или

```
bool is_deg3(const int num) {
    int value = num;

    while (value % 3 == 0) {
        value /= 3;
    }

    return value == 1;
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант возвращает `true` для числа `1'870'418'611` ([пример](https://ideone.com/uD9dRU)),  однако оно не является степенью тройки. Второй вариант зацикливается, если в функцию передать ноль.

Comment: @wololo - 0 не натуральное число :), а разговор шел про натуральные, но проверку добавить можно конечно дополнительную

Comment: @wololo, действительно из-за переполнения возникал такой баг - исправил код :)

Comment: @Zhihar Спасибо большое за помощь )

Answer (score 3):

Вот так придумал:

```
/**
 * Много ложноположительных срабатываний начиная с 450283905890997362
 */
bool is_pow3(unsigned long long num) {
    long double d = logl(num) / logl(3);


    return d - (int) d < 3.46945e-18;
}

bool is_pow3_pow(unsigned long long num) {
    int d = logl(num) / logl(3);


    return num == powl(3, d);
}
```

Ну или:

```
static set<unsigned long long> power3{
    1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147, 531441, 1594323, 4782969, 14348907, 43046721, 129140163, 387420489,
    1162261467, 3486784401, 10460353203, 31381059609, 94143178827, 282429536481, 847288609443, 2541865828329, 7625597484987, 22876792454961,
    68630377364883, 205891132094649, 617673396283947, 1853020188851841, 5559060566555523, 16677181699666569, 50031545098999707, 150094635296999121,
    450283905890997363, 1350851717672992089, 4052555153018976267, 12157665459056928801u};

bool is_num_power_of_3(unsigned long long num) {
    return power3.count(num);
}
```

Comment: а почему 1e-8 для double!!!!!

Comment: А сколько надо? 14? 15? Я просто в самом log не очень уверен) Мало ли что там накопится)

Comment: а вот это как раз более интересная задача :) найти такой контрпример при котором 1e-8 дает сбой :)

Comment: стало интересно, посмотрел метод - в общем начиная с 129140162 начинается беда :) правда дельта 7.04846e-09, у степеней троек дельта все таки ниже 1e-15 не опускается

Comment: В общем 1e-14 само то)

Comment: кстати если брать не double, а float, то в 1e8 пролезает 3000 с копейками чисел :)

Comment: Первый вариант возвращает `true` для числа `50'031'545'098'999'704`, но оно не является степенью тройки. [Пример](https://ideone.com/1iVi63).

Comment: @wololo, вы можете изменить тип на long double и уменьшить эпсилон)

Comment: Заменил на `long double`, уменьшил `eps`. [Не помогло](https://rextester.com/CHIOY32747) :)

Comment: Хм, тут stdlib похоже всё. pow(3, 35) возвращает как раз ваше число))

Comment: Кстати, в gcc всё гораздо лучше

Comment: `pow(3, 35)` может и рада вернуть точный результат, вот только вещественное число `3**35` не представимо 64-битным числом с плавающей точкой. [Пример](https://ideone.com/si8tNV).

Comment: Я не тот pow видимо дёргал) https://godbolt.org/z/3Gfo3a

Comment: Хорошая попытка, [но...](https://ideone.com/P6j4RR) :)

Comment: Всё, финиш, последний вариант, надоело с ветряными мельницами бороться))

Comment: Эх, а я думал добъёте до идеального состояния)) Или [проблемы](https://rextester.com/KKAO16917) пользователей студии шерифа не волнуют :))

Comment: В этих ваших студиях похоже вообще long double отсутствует [?](https://rextester.com/HVSKS83118) Это не починить, только что-то другое изобразить)

Comment: Я бы и с GCC был [начеку](https://rextester.com/JGHGA64981). (Тест на внимательность :)))

Comment: -mlong-double-64

Comment: Ок, ладно, вы на начеку. Засим откланиваюсь)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115669/discussion-on-answer-by-vp-arth-----k--3).

Answer (score 3):

Перевести в троичную систему и если получится число вида 100..000 (любое количество нулей), то это - степень 3.

Comment: нафига так много действий? просто берем ЭВМ "Сетунь"

Comment: Можно дополнить ответ, что в этом случае решением будет нечто вроде `x & (x-1)`. Нужно только интерполировать смысл оператора & на троичную логику))